# Making openssl macros in linux with C

Tags: c, linux, openssl, macros

I am trying to create an automation system for renewing ssl cert using openssl on linux. The method I decided to go with was created a C program, with my first step being to have the program run the initiating openssl command and autofill in the fields that proceed after with variables that I predefined. How do accomplish this? I understand how to run basic commands from C using system(), but i am not sure how to have it continue to enter the actual fields

Comment: What does this have to do with C? Unless you're planning on using the OpenSSL C API to perform the task you're describing; it doesn't sound like it is related whatsoever. This sounds like a "how do I skip/fulfill prompts during certificate renewal using the OpenSSL command-line interface?"

Comment: is there way to do this with just a script? Or rather, is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've probably selected the most complicated solution possible. First, if you're primarily just going to be calling other programs, `C` isn't going to get you much. Second, you absolutely don't want to try to fill in interactive prompts if you can avoid it (and you can!).

For example, to create a CSR for `server.example.com` without any interactive prompting, we can run something like:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server.key -out server.csr \
  -sha256 -days 365 -subj /CN=server.example.com
```

This creates `server.key` and `server.csr`.

Lastly, for certificate *renewal*, you should just be able to re-use an existing CSR.

Comment: How would you reuse the existing form?

Comment: The way you generate a certificate is by signing a certificate signing request (CSR). Whether you are running your own CA or interacting with another CA, you should be able to resubmit the same CSR and have it signed.